# Where can I find online a good recording of Gemorah which explains it very well peshuta shel talmud

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, internet, talmud-bavli

Where can I find online a good recording of Gemorah which explains it very well peshuta shel talmud?

I do not need a lot of mephorshim just someone who explains very well and clear the peshuta shel talmud.

(I do not think it is needed but I am want it for Mesechta Rosh Hashana)

Answer (score 2):

[DafYomi.org](http://www.dafyomi.org/download.php?masechta=rosh_hashana) - downloads page. By [Rabbi Dovid Grossman](http://www.dafyomi.org/aboutrg.php)

Comment: I already tried him, he is good but does not explain enough.

Answer (score 1):

[livedaf.net](http://livedaf.net/) has video and recordings. There are Pshat and elucidations separately.